# Drawable passed through startActivityForResult not printing to PDF page

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

In my project users are presented with a 'Create' activity that holds text or image CardViews to represent pages in a PDF file. These pages are then saved to a PDF document for viewing. However, user-selected images are not printing inside the PDF document. But when I add an image programmatically, it is being printed to PDF and I can't figure out why the user-selected one isn't.

Images are inserted via an onItemClickListener in a GridView gallery activity. The user clicks "Add Image" in the Create activity and is directed to the GridView gallery via startActivityForResult. The 'clicked' image is then passed through as an Intent to the Create activity via onActivityResult. Here is my code for both activities.

Create activity:

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//firebase auth
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

//public variables
public String currentUserAccount;
public String teacherAccountNav = "Teacher";
public String currentUserId;

ViewPager viewPager;
CreateAdapter createAdapter;
List<PdfPage> pdfPageList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

    currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    //image added PROGRAMMATICALLY test
    pdfPageList.add(new PdfPage("", "Image", R.drawable.a_blues_scale_android, "Scale"));

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    createAdapter = new CreateAdapter(pdfPageList, this);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(createAdapter);
    viewPager.setPadding(130, 0, 130, 0);

    createAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CreateAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEditClick(int position) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_text_dialog, null);
            builder.setView(dialogView);

            final EditText enterText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addTextEditText);
            final Button addTextButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addNewTextButton);

            final PdfPage pdfPage = pdfPageList.get(position);

            enterText.setText(pdfPage.getPageText());

            final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

            addTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pdfPage.setPageText(enterText.getText().toString().trim());

                    Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "Text Page Edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    onStart();
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
            pdfPageList.remove(position);
            Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "Page Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onStart();
        }
    });
}

public void onAddImageClick(View view){
    showAddImageDialog();
}

private void showAddImageDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_gallery_selection_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final Button buttonChord = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.chordButton);
    final Button buttonScale = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.scaleButton);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    buttonChord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, ChordGalleryActivity.class);
            //startActivity for result
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    buttonScale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==2) {
        if (resultCode == 2) {
            PdfPage pdfPage = new PdfPage();

            assert data != null;
            pdfPage.setPageImage(data.getIntExtra("DIAGRAM_RES", 0));
            pdfPage.setImageType(data.getStringExtra("DIAGRAM_TYPE"));
            pdfPage.setPageType("Image");
            pdfPage.setPageText("");


            pdfPageList.add(pdfPage);
            Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "Image Page Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            onStart();
        } else if (resultCode == 1) {
            //result from back button
            onStart();
        }
    }
}

public void onSaveClicked(View view){
    showSaveDialog();
}

private void showSaveDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    //dialog XML
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.save_pdf_dialog,null);

    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText enterFileName = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.pdfNameEditText);
    final ImageButton buttonNo = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonNo4);
    final ImageButton buttonYes = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonYes4);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    buttonYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String fileName = enterFileName.getText().toString().trim();

            //PDF Document creation
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

            //for loop for arrayList new page
            int i = 0;
            for(PdfPage userDoc : pdfPageList){

                userDoc.getPageType();
                userDoc.getPageText();
                userDoc.getPageImage();
                userDoc.getImageType();

                //write text to page if page type is "Text"
                if(userDoc.getPageType().equals("Text")){
                    //create a page info description
                    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(900, 1280, i+1).create();

                    //start a page
                    PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);

                    //writing to new page
                    Paint paint = new Paint();

                    //setting font and text size
                    paint.setTextSize(26);
                    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Arial", Typeface.NORMAL));

                    //canvas used to write to page, getting object data from inputted text
                    String myString = userDoc.getPageText();

                    //setting where to start text on the page
                    int x = 10, y = 25;
                    //multi line loop
                    for(String line : myString.split("\n")){
                        page.getCanvas().drawText(line, x, y, paint);
                        y+=paint.descent()-paint.ascent();
                    }
                    //finish page
                    pdfDocument.finishPage(page);

                    //add to page count
                    i++;
                }else if(userDoc.getPageType().equals("Image")){ //write to page if page type is "Image"
                    //create a page info description
                    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(900, 1280, i+1).create();

                    //start a page
                    PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);

                    //writing to new page
                    Paint paint = new Paint();

                    //this gets the resource files bitmap
                    int imageFile = userDoc.getPageImage();
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageFile);

                    //writing image to page
                    if(userDoc.getImageType() == "Scale") {
                        page.getCanvas().drawBitmap(image, 0, 250, paint);
                    }else if(userDoc.getImageType() == "Chord"){
                        page.getCanvas().drawBitmap(image, 250, 250, paint);
                    }

                    //finish page
                    pdfDocument.finishPage(page);

                    //add to page count
                    i++;
                }
            }

            String folder_main = "/GuitarAppStorage";

            //get or create parent folder for app
            String rootPath = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            File parentFolder = new File(rootPath + folder_main);
            if(!parentFolder.exists()){
                parentFolder.mkdirs();
            }

            //get or create child folder with currentUserId as folder name
            File childFolder = new File(rootPath + folder_main, currentUserId);
            if(!childFolder.exists()){
                childFolder.mkdirs();
            }

            //new file with path and filename
            File file = new File(childFolder, fileName+".pdf");

            //write to folder
            try{
                pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
                Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "File Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "Error: File not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            alertDialog.dismiss();
            onStart();

        }
    });
}
```

Gallery activity:

```
public class ChordGalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<Diagram> diagramList = new ArrayList<>();
GridView gridView;
DiagramAdapter diagramAdapter;
SearchView searchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chord_gallery);

    //add chords to diagram list
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("C Major", "Chord", R.drawable.cmajor_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("C Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.cm_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("C# Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.c_sharp_m_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("Db Major", "Chord", R.drawable.db_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("D Major", "Chord", R.drawable.d_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("D Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.dm_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("Eb Major", "Chord", R.drawable.e_flat_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("E Major", "Chord", R.drawable.e_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("E Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.em_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("F Major", "Chord", R.drawable.f_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("F Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.fm_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("F# Major", "Chord", R.drawable.f_sharp__android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("F# Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.f_sharp_m_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("G Major", "Chord", R.drawable.g_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("G Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.gm_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("G# Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.g_sharp_m_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("Ab Major", "Chord", R.drawable.a_flat_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("A Major", "Chord", R.drawable.a_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("A Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.am_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("Bb Major", "Chord", R.drawable.b_flat_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("Bb Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.bbm_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("B Major", "Chord", R.drawable.b_android));
    diagramList.add(new Diagram("B Minor", "Chord", R.drawable.bm_android));

    //initialise views
    gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    //set adapter
    diagramAdapter = new DiagramAdapter(diagramList, this);

    //set adapter to gridView
    gridView.setAdapter(diagramAdapter);

    //click listeners go here
    diagramAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new DiagramAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            final Diagram diagram = diagramList.get(position);

            int res = diagram.getDiagramRes();
            String type = diagram.getDiagramType();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("DIAGRAM_RES", res);
            intent.putExtra("DIAGRAM_TYPE", type);
            setResult(2, intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

I have a "Diagram" model which holds the object data for the images and a "PdfPage" model that holds the object data for new pages that have been added. Here is the code for my models.

Diagram model (the image):

```
public class Diagram {
private String diagramName;
private String diagramType;
private int diagramRes;

public Diagram() {
}

public Diagram(String diagramName, String diagramType, int diagramRes) {
    this.diagramName = diagramName;
    this.diagramType = diagramType;
    this.diagramRes = diagramRes;
}

public String getDiagramName() {
    return diagramName;
}

public void setDiagramName(String diagramName) {
    this.diagramName = diagramName;
}

public String getDiagramType() {
    return diagramType;
}

public void setDiagramType(String diagramType) {
    this.diagramType = diagramType;
}

public int getDiagramRes() {
    return diagramRes;
}

public void setDiagramRes(int diagramRes) {
    this.diagramRes = diagramRes;
}
```

PdfPage model:

```
public class PdfPage {
private String pageText;
private String pageType;
private int pageImage;
private String imageType;

public PdfPage() {
}

public PdfPage(String pageText, String pageType, int pageImage, String imageType) {
    this.pageText = pageText;
    this.pageType = pageType;
    this.pageImage = pageImage;
    this.imageType = imageType;
}

public String getPageText() {
    return pageText;
}

public void setPageText(String pageText) {
    this.pageText = pageText;
}

public String getPageType() {
    return pageType;
}

public void setPageType(String pageType) {
    this.pageType = pageType;
}

public int getPageImage() {
    return pageImage;
}

public void setPageImage(int pageImage) {
    this.pageImage = pageImage;
}

public String getImageType() {
    return imageType;
}

public void setImageType(String imageType) {
    this.imageType = imageType;
}
```

The added image shows up in my Create activity CardView which suggests that the Intent putExtra has worked but when I save the PDF document and open it, the image has not printed to PDF but a new blank page has. When I add a new image programmatically in onCreate it prints to PDF and can be viewed in the PDF document. Why are my user-selected images not printing to the PDF document but my programmatically added images are?

Here are my adapters for reference.

CreateAdapter:

```
public class CreateAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<PdfPage> pagesList;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
private onItemClickListener mListener;

public interface onItemClickListener{
    //click method for edit button
    void onEditClick(int position);
    //click method for delete button
    void onDeleteClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

public CreateAdapter(List<PdfPage> pagesList, Context context) {
    this.pagesList = pagesList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pagesList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = null;

    if(pagesList.get(position).getPageType() == "Text") {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_text_cardview, container, false);

        TextView inputText = view.findViewById(R.id.inputTextView);
        ImageButton editButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonEdit);
        ImageButton deleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDelete);
        
        inputText.setText(pagesList.get(position).getPageText());

        //edit click listener
        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null){
                    int position2 = pagesList.indexOf(pagesList.get(position));
                    mListener.onEditClick(position2);
                }
            }
        });

        //delete click listener
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null){
                    int position3 = pagesList.indexOf(pagesList.get(position));
                    mListener.onDeleteClick(position3);
                }
            }
        });

        container.addView(view, 0);


    }else if(pagesList.get(position).getPageType() == "Image"){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_image_cardview, container, false);

        ImageView inputImage = view.findViewById(R.id.inputImageView);
        ImageButton deleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDelete);

        //image getter
        inputImage.setImageResource(pagesList.get(position).getPageImage());

        //delete click listener
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null){
                    int position4 = pagesList.indexOf(pagesList.get(position));
                    mListener.onDeleteClick(position4);
                }
            }
        });

        container.addView(view, 0);
    }

    assert view != null;
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}
```

DiagramAdapter:

```
public class DiagramAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Diagram> list;
private Context context;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

public DiagramAdapter(List<Diagram> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Diagram diagram = list.get(position);

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.diagram_card_view, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView diagramImage = view.findViewById(R.id.diagramImageView);
    TextView diagramName = view.findViewById(R.id.diagramNameTextView);

    int image = diagram.getDiagramRes();
    String name = diagram.getDiagramName();

    diagramImage.setImageResource(image);
    diagramName.setText(name);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null){
                int position2 = list.indexOf(list.get(position));
                mListener.onItemClick(position2);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```